# How to convert OS X Dashboard widget to desktop app?

Tags: terminal, macos, dashboard, widgets

I would like to convert a OS X Dashboard widget to a desktop app, namely the Stocks widget. I understand I could move the widget to the desktop using terminal to enable developer mode for Dashboard but I'm only interested in the functionality of an app such as [Amnesty Singles](http://www.mesadynamics.com), however I do not wish to use third-party applications to achieve this and wondering if it is possible to use Terminal to create the stand alone application with the widget?
I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11.2 but most Terminal commands since Snow Leopard should work.

Comment: It would improve your question to eliminate the references to “terminal,” as I’m sure you don’t care whether the solution involves using a terminal, and it would eliminate some noise from the `terminal` tag, which is for questions specifically about terminals.

Comment: I do care that it uses Terminal as I don't want to use a third-party app, but you're half right, if there is another way to achieve the same without using third-party applications then I'm listening.

Comment: Let me put it this way: by asking how to do it with Terminal and tagging this with ‘terminal’ you're being too specific about the solution instead of asking how to solve the problem, and you are narrowing the potential audience of people who might know the answer.